# systemFont with weight

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfont

In OS X, is there any api to get system font with special weight? In iOS, I found the api `systemFontOfSize:weight:`, but there is no one like this in OS X.

I have tried `[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] convertWeight:NO ofFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:10]]`, but it does not return a valid font with smaller weight.

And I do not want to hardcode using `Helvetica UltraLight`, because I hope it could change to San Francisco in 10.11. By the way, I do not find the new San Francisco in FontBook, what is its font name?

Comment: I noticed that Xcode 7 can support changing weight of system font in IB, and 10.11 add the api, but any method for 10.10 and below?

Comment: it seems that 10.10 supports the call of `systemFontOfSize:weight:`, but not as a documented api, maybe we can call it using `NSInvocation`.

Answer (score 0):

As of macOS 10.11, [`+[NSFont systemFontOfSize:weight:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/1524930-systemfontofsize?language=objc) does exist.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/1524930-systemfontofsize?language=objc